# Gitlab CI/CD pipeline, check subfolder names and create Docker images

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration

I have a repo containing a bunch of subfolders, each with a Dockerfile, and two configuration files.

```
subfolder_00
-- Dockerfile

subfolder_01
-- Dockerfile

.gitlab-ci.yml
.gitlab-ci-templates.yaml
```

I'm trying to configure a Gitlab CI/CD pipeline, so that if a new tag version is created the pipeline will:

- go through the subfolders;
- for each of them, build the image corresponding to the Dockerfile in the subfolder;
- push the image to the registry;

I know how to do it manually for a single subfolder if I have:

```
# .gitlab-ci-templates.yaml

.base-build-docker:
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.9.0-debug
    entrypoint: ['']
  stage: package
  variables:
    DOCKERFILE: 'Dockerfile'
    CONTEXT: ''
    SERVICE_IMAGE_TAG: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    REGISTRY_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$MODULE
    PREFIX: ''
  script:
    - mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"${CI_REGISTRY}\":{\"auth\":\"$(printf "%s:%s" "${CI_REGISTRY_USER}" "${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}" | base64 | tr -d '\n')\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - /kaniko/executor --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR/$CONTEXT --dockerfile $DOCKERFILE --destination $REGISTRY_IMAGE:${SERVICE_IMAGE_TAG#"$PREFIX"}
  only:
    refs:
      - tags
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_TAG
```

```
# .gitlab-ci.yml

include:
  - .gitlab-ci-templates.yaml

stages:
  - build

docker-build:
  stage: build
  extends:
    - .base-build-docker
  variables:
    CONTEXT: subfolder_00
    MODULE: docker_images
    DOCKERFILE: Dockerfile
```

So, in my example I'm manually passing the context (subfolder_00) for a single file, so that specific Dockerfile is used for building/pushing the image. But how can I do this automatically?

I know that I could use a for loop inside a script section, like:

```
  script:
    - |
      for dockerfile in $(find . -name "Dockerfile" | sort -r); do
        context=$(dirname $dockerfile)
      done
```

but I don't know how to iteratively call .base-build-docker after obtaining the various subfolder names (and hence the context for the Dockerfiles).